# How to redirect to another class component/Page in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router, react-router-dom, multi-page-application

How to redirect from one class component to another class component/fresh page in ReactJS.

Currently, I am able to load new components through the link tags in react-router.
but then I want to redirect to another class component just like href in HTML to another fresh page where the previous states will not be available and it's a fresh new class.

> **Example:-**  
>  
>  I have 3 Pages
>
> 1. LandingPage
> 2. LoginPage
> 3. SignupPage

Initially, LandingPage will be opened and after that when I click the respective screen it will open.
How can i load a fresh *LoginPage* & *SignupPage* from *LandingPage*. Both SignupPage and LandingPage have a separate class component to manage the state of that particular screens.
Please share some code references.

Thanks in advance..  :)

Comment: React doesn't provide out of the box routing capabilities.you have to use other modules like `react-router`, `reach-router` etc :)

Comment: yeah, so how can i route using the above modules ??? Note ;- i did'nt want to load a component but then to route to a fresh page which has a different class

Comment: @abhikumar22 That is a correct behavior. As react mentioned state has to be local for the components. To share the state to multiple components you have to either 1. **lift the state up**, 2. use **Context api** or 3. use **redux** for the centralizing the state.

Comment: Go through the example given by react-router-> https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic It clearly explains how to achieve the solution you require

Comment: @akhilchoudhary read the question correctly, i have stated that "Currently i am able to load new component through link tag in react router"...i need to load a class componet from another class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open login or signup page from landing page you can simply call `history.push('/login')` from landing page component to open login page. history is available in every route so can be called directly.

index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import landingPage from './landingPage';
import login from './login';
import signup from './signup';

    render(){
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact={true} path="/" component={landingPage} />
                  <Route exact={true} path="/login" component={login} />
                  <Route exact={true} path="/signup" component={signup} />
                </Switch>
           </BrowserRouter>
    }
```

//landing page component

```
landingPage =()=>{
  const openLoginPage= () => {
    history.push('/login'); //this will open login page on click of login button
}

return(<div> 
          < button onClick={openLoginPage}>login</button >
       </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will it help to reach your idea? I just share you the idea of routing in react using **`react-router-dom`**

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "./signUp";
import Login from "./login";
import Landing from "./landing";

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div id="container">
          <div>
            <Link to="/">Landing</Link>
            <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
            <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
          </div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You have supposedly created your functional component/ class component, you may import and use accordingly

**Update for the class components**

Once the routed from one component to another component each component will load with its own **`state`** and **`props`**

I have put here my class components, you have to make sure all App.js, landing.jsx, signUp.jsx and login.jsx are on the same folder location

**landing.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Landing extends Component {
state={}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Landing page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Landing;
```

**signUp.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SignUp extends Component {
state={}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sign Up page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

**login.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Login extends Component {
state={}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Another way is use **`push`** method on button click inside class components, and in both cases route should be there

```
<button onClick={()=> this.props.history.push('/')} ></button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={()=> this.props.history.push('/signup')} ></button>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the effort, but then i have already mentioned that i already used link tag. Now i want to route to a class component from another class component just like the above App.js

Comment: if you have the same named components on same level with App.js then initially it supposed to show you the landing page based on route, with menu of 3 items at the top, the if you click sugnup it will load the signup component, are we on the same level or I got you wrongly

Comment: No, lets take an example, i have the 3 page just like App.js what you have written.
Than From !st page i have to navigate to 2nd page...it means and page also have a class and 3rd page also. So i don't want to load a component rather than navigate to a different component

Comment: like if you redirect to signup class component there will be no landing class component?

Comment: yeah....it is just a fresh component.<br> Rather that loading a simple component into a class. I need to navigate to different class component to manage the three page states differently. I want to make a multipage application

Comment: I have updated my answer, will it work now for you?